# Compute the Tor without using M2

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R=[|x,y,z|]$, be a formal power series ring. I want to compute the $Tor_1(R/(x),R/(x)\oplus(R/(y,z))$. I am trying to compute without using Macaulay 2, but I could not. I know $$Tor_1(R/I,R/J)\cong I\cap J/IJ.$$ where $I$ and $J$ are ideals of $I$.Also,$$Tor_1(R/(x),R/(x)\oplus(R/(y,z)))= Tor_1(R/x,R/(x))\oplus Tor_1(R/(x),R/(y,z)).$$

If I am not mistaken, the answer is $$Tor_1(R/(x),R/(x)\oplus(R/(y,z)))=R/(x).$$ This is by Macaulay 2. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want us to show $(x)/(x^2)\simeq R/(x)$ and $(x)\cap (y,z)=(x)(y,z)$?

Comment: Thank you user26857, I already got the second isomorphism, but I still have difficulty with first. I attempted to define a map directly, it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

I got the idea and here it is

since the $(x)$ and $(y,z)$ are co-prime ideals then this shows that $(x)\cap (y,z)= (x)(y,z).$  For the second isomorphic, it can be done by define a a map $f: R\rightarrow (x)/(x^2)$   by $f(r)=rx+(x^2).$ We still need to that $ker f=(x^2).$it is easy since $x\in ker(f).$ By showing that $ker f=(x^2)$, we will be done. but it is easy to see that.